# Node.js EXDEV rename error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been playing with some code I found in a book about Node.js. It is a simple app which uploads images.

It shows the EXDEV error (500 Error: EXDEV, rename).

Could someone give me a hint? Here's my code:

```
exports.submit = function(dir) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var img = req.files.photo.image;
        var name = req.body.photo.name || img.name;
        var path = join(dir, img.name);

        fs.rename(img.path, path, function (err) {
            if(err) return next(err);

            Photo.create({
                name: name,
                path: img.name
            }, function (err) {
                if(err) return next(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 21):

Renaming files cannot be done cross-device. My guess is that your upload directory (which by default is `/tmp`) is on another partition/drive as your target directory (contained in the `dir` variable).

Some solutions:

- configure the upload directory to be on the same partition/drive as your target directory; this depends on which module you're using to handle file uploads, `express.bodyParser` (and the module it uses, [`connect.multipart`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html)) accepts an `uploadDir` option that you can use;
- before starting your Node app, set the `TMPDIR` environment variable to point to a temporary directory on the same partition/drive as your target directory. If you're using a Unix-type OS:

  ```
  env TMPDIR=/path/to/directory node app.js
  ```
- instead of setting the environment variable from your shell, set it at the top of your Node app:

  ```
  process.env.TMPDIR = '/path/to/directory';
  ```
- instead of renaming, use a module like [`mv`](https://npmjs.org/package/mv) that *can* work cross-device;

Comment: its better to use shell, then your paths are not in the source. Good strategy for passwords, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows XP, I added to app.js:

```
process.env.TMPDIR = '.';  //new
```

Comment: A cleaner solution is to use the `npm mv` module instead of `fs.rename()`. See `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv`.