# NodeJS Buffer Base64 File Limits

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, restify

Tried to upload an image using Base64 but if the string is long the bottom of the stored image is blank white.

#### upload.js

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.uploadImage = function(base64Str, callback) {
    var filename = uuid.v1()+'.png';
    var bitmap = new Buffer(base64Str, 'base64');
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, bitmap);
    callback(filename);
};
```

#### server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var restify = require('restify');  
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

var upload = require('./modules/upload');

server.post('/images', function(req, res) {
    upload.uploadImage(req.params.myImage, function(filename) {
        console.log('processing image');
        res.send(filename);
        res.end();
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

It works for a string of length 499016 bytes but not if the string is 847508 bytes. Is there a documented size limit and, if not, how can I upload and un-encode longer strings?

Comment: if the image comes from a browser, i would suspect it more than node...

Comment: I am converting the image using an online encoder then passing it to node using Chrome Postman. I suspected the online encoder tool so used a second one but got the same result.

Comment: make sure you are writing as binary, maybe some images fool the encoding detector, and you don't specify "binary"...

Comment: Small images decode perfectly and larger images decide partially yet remember the overall image size. Is there a timeout issue with NodeJS?

Comment: there should not be, but you should use async anyway. perhaps the OS is reporting the write complete before the HDD actually archives it. does delaying the turn-around help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be hitting a request size limit. One alternative would be to upload your image as `multipart/form-data`. You can do this with the `mapFiles` options in `restify.bodyParser`, and you can test it by choosing file instead of text in your Postman form-data.

**Edited:** `fs.rename` might make more sense here for testing purposes. In a practical application you might want to save uploaded files elsewhere, on s3 perhaps.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser({
    mapFiles: true
}));

var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var fs = require('fs');

var uploadImage = function(path, callback) {
    var filename = uuid.v1() + '.png';
    fs.rename(path, filename, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        callback(filename);
    });
};

server.post('/images', function(req, res) {
    uploadImage(req.files.myImage.path, function(filename) {
        res.send(filename);
        res.end();
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Because my temp dir was on a different partition I got an EXDEV error. There were two possible changes to the above, either move my temp dir `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071303/node-js-exdev-rename-error` or substitute the `npm mv` module for `fs.rename`. I chose the latter and everything works well.

Comment: Whilst the answer works well, I would still like to understand how to upload a large image base64 encoded. I have tried setting the bodyParser hoping this would fix things. Has anyone got any ideas?